# Using neomodel to generate JSON for graph visualisation in Javascript

Tags: django, d3.js, neo4j, cypher, neomodel

I'm using `neomodel` in a django app to query `Neo4j`. Everything is fine but I can't figure out how to get a full path to be generated so that I can use d3 to visualise part of the graph in javascript - so ideally I need this in JSON. I can get a list of nodes from a CYPHER query in neomodel but how do I inflate nodes and relationships?

I have found some examples of how to use the REST interface directly which suggests using `"resultDataContents":["graph"]` at the end of the request but there doesn't appear to be anything within `neomodel` to duplicate this functionality. Is there something I should add to the end of my cypher or something in neomodel I haven't found yet?